# Confusion over Startup, Global, Application and Session

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, owin

I am trying to understand the various ways of storing and instantiating Application (i.e. objects available to every user) and Session level (objects created and available to users only for their session) variables.  Also, how does OWIN fit into all of this?

1. Global.asax.cs - This can contain a bunch of different methods.  I believe that Application_Start is only called during the first request.  However, there are a few candidates here for methods to populate session level variables (e.g. Session_Start and Application_BeginRequest).  What is the standard way of doing this?
2. There is also the Startup class used by OWIN.  I get that OWIN lets you store Application level variables, but why wouldn't you just use the HttpApplicationState Application variable accessible from Global.asax.cs to accomplish this?  Also - can OWIN handle Session variables?

Comment: I think you should split and refocus your questions to foster engagement with people here on SO. You may want to offer a scenario, too, so readers can frame the problem and offer answers more tailored to your needs.

At the moment you're fishing for someone that knows the answer to all these things combined, whereas statistically its more likely individuals will know how to answer single specific questions.

Comment: For instance, my application is multi-tenanted.  I need to parse the requested domain and store it in a way so that anything in the context of that request can access it to see what context it exists in (i.e. which site).

Comment: Reword the question William, take out the OWIN stuff and put that in its own question once you have an answer to the first one. The answer might sway your line of enquiry about OWIN.

Comment: I guess my biggest issue is that I don't know how to ask the question correctly - from my perspective, OWIN is only used to store Application level variables, which seems to overlap exactly with the Application variable in Global.asax.cs - but I'm guessing that it is capable of doing a lot more than that as well?

Comment: I think you have a misunderstanding of what OWIN is and what it is used for.

Comment: I do indeed.  Do you have any resources to help me understand?

Answer (score 0):

> "I believe that Application_Start is only called during the first
>   request."

Only for the first request after calling the web application. For instance, this is the case after deploying, ApplicationPool Recycling, restarting or coming out of sleep.

Let's assume 3 users visit your web application. `Application_Start` will only be called for one of them, specifically the first one that visits it. Therefore it is not suited for populating user-specific session values.

> However, there are a few candidates here for methods to populate session level variables (e.g. Session_Start and Application_BeginRequest). What is the standard way of doing this?

In the past I've worked with `Session_Start` to initialize user-specific session values (like default values) on numerous projects and never had an issue with it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm really not sure what the question is, as I said in the comments. I'm going to ignore the OWIN stuff since I don't know, frankly.

Firstly, try not to store state at all. Design to pass state back and forth between server and client in models, or the URL, even in the HTML on the client such as in the URLs in the `<a>` tags your rendering, or (rarely) in cookies, rather than keep things in memory. Stateless designs are way more scalable.

Storing state isn't "usually" done in the `Global.asax` but then what's usual? I store state as and when I need it, load it or otherwise come by that data. For me in MVC, that's usually downstream of a Controller action, maybe while logging someone in, or reading some data received in a model, like a customer clicking 'add to cart'.

Application state I rarely use, though I store long-lived and shared data within normal fields and properties in long-lived static classes. These die when the app is recycled, but I don't usually care since the apps are designed to work without it, stateless; its usually cached bits of data.

Also, `Session_Start` only fires when a new browser/agent hits the site. You don't know the user at that point.

The methods in the `Global.asax` were not specifically designed for 'bootstrapping' state-loading, they're just convenient events for doing whatever you want with. You don't have to use them at all, mine usually just contain logging so I know when sessions start etc.!

I don't know if this helps.

Once you have a plan, come back and ask a targeted question about the OWIN stuff.